# Python -= A Space from a String

Tags: python, string, subtraction

I am trying to remove a space from a string inside of a for loop. I was able to get it working for adding a space, but removing does not work.

Here is my code:

```
letterHeight = 10

def nLetter():
    x = 0
    diagonal = ""
    vertical = "          "
    while x < letterHeight:
        print "*"+diagonal+"*"+vertical+"*"
        diagonal += " "
        vertical -= " "
        x += 1

nLetter()
```

Error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'str' and 'str'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings don't support subtraction; which one of the spaces should be removed? Use slicing instead:

```
vertical = vertical[:-1]
```

This removes the last character by creating a new string from all the characters except the last one:

```
>>> "abcd"[:-1]
'abc'
```

Comment: Awesome. Works perfect. Good to know that strings don't support subtraction. What is the reason for that, and is that the same across other languages? Thanks.

Comment: @Nicolas: None of the sequence types (list, tuple, string) support subtraction, because it is ambiguous as to what element would be removed. Most languages treat sequences like that; appending is easy as that just adds the element at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can try string formatting to do this!

```
letterHeight = 10

def nLetter():
    diagonal = 1
    vertical = 10
    for _ in range(letterHeight):
        print("*{2:>{0}}{2:>{1}}".format(diagonal, vertical, "*"))
        diagonal += 1
        vertical -= 1

nLetter()
```

Or slightly better:

```
def nLetter():
    for mod in range(letterHeight):
        print("*{2:>{0}}{2:>{1}}".format(1+mod, 10-mod, "*"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `-=` operator with strings. If you need to remove the last character from a string (not necessarily a space), try this:

```
vertical = vertical[:-1]
```